# Trying to update distinct records and having issue figuring out how to do it

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct, updates

I'm trying to update a set of distinct records in an Oracle 11g database, and having a little trouble figuring it out. I'm able to select the records I want to update no problem, but keep running into issues when I try to update.

To select the records I want to update, I can select them with this query:

```
select  distinct p.irp_pla_platenbr, v.irp_veh_vin, v.irp_veh_titlenbr, vd.vin, vd.vehicle_unique, vd.title_number, vd.plate_reg, vd.year_reg, p.irp_pla_year, p.irp_pla_status
from irp.irp_vehicles  v
inner join irp.irp_fleetvehicleregistration fvr on fvr.irp_fvr_vehicleid = v.irp_veh_id
inner join irp.irp_plates p on p.irp_pla_vehicleid = fvr.irp_fvr_vehicleid and p.irp_pla_status = 'A'
inner join VINDECODE.veh_2019 vd on vd.title_number = v.irp_veh_titlenbr
where v.irp_veh_regdate >= '01-NOV-19'
and p.irp_pla_platenbr <> vd.plate_reg
and vd.plate_reg like 'A%'
```

From here, I'd like to update this set of distinct records by setting p.irp_pla_platenbr = vd.plate_reg;

I've attempted it a couple of ways:

Attempt 1:

```
UPDATE
  (
select  distinct p.irp_pla_platenbr, v.irp_veh_vin, v.irp_veh_titlenbr, vd.vin, vd.vehicle_unique, vd.title_number, vd.plate_reg, vd.year_reg, p.irp_pla_year, p.irp_pla_status
from irp.irp_vehicles  v
inner join irp.irp_fleetvehicleregistration fvr on fvr.irp_fvr_vehicleid = v.irp_veh_id
inner join irp.irp_plates p on p.irp_pla_vehicleid = fvr.irp_fvr_vehicleid and p.irp_pla_status = 'A'
inner join VINDECODE.veh_2019 vd on vd.title_number = v.irp_veh_titlenbr
where v.irp_veh_regdate >= '01-NOV-19'
and p.irp_pla_platenbr <> vd.plate_reg
and vd.plate_reg like 'A%'
  )
set p.irp_pla_platenbr = vd.plate_reg;
```

Attempt 2:

```
update irp_plates set irp_pla_platenbr =
    (select  vd.plate_reg
    from irp.irp_vehicles  v
    inner join irp.irp_fleetvehicleregistration fvr on fvr.irp_fvr_vehicleid = v.irp_veh_id
    inner join irp.irp_plates p on p.irp_pla_vehicleid = fvr.irp_fvr_vehicleid and p.irp_pla_status = 'A'
    inner join VINDECODE.veh_2019 vd on vd.title_number = v.irp_veh_titlenbr
    where v.irp_veh_regdate >= '01-NOV-19'
    and p.irp_pla_platenbr <> vd.plate_reg
    and vd.plate_reg like 'A%')
where exists
    (select  distinct p.irp_pla_platenbr, v.irp_veh_vin, v.irp_veh_titlenbr, vd.vin, vd.vehicle_unique, vd.title_number, vd.plate_reg, vd.year_reg, p.irp_pla_year, p.irp_pla_status
    from irp_vehicles  v
    inner join irp.irp_fleetvehicleregistration fvr on fvr.irp_fvr_vehicleid = v.irp_veh_id
    inner join irp.irp_plates p on p.irp_pla_vehicleid = fvr.irp_fvr_vehicleid and p.irp_pla_status = 'A'
    inner join VINDECODE.veh_2019 vd on vd.title_number = v.irp_veh_titlenbr
    where v.irp_veh_regdate >= '01-NOV-19'
    and p.irp_pla_platenbr <> vd.plate_reg
    and vd.plate_reg like 'A%');
```

I keep getting errors, haven't had any luck figuring out how to update this.
Any ideas or suggestions would be very much appreciated.
Thanks
Chris

Comment: update your question and add the exact error message

Comment: What errors do you get? Remember we cannot see your screen and we cannot run your code. We only know what you tell us.

Answer (score 0):

You coul try avoidig the DISTINCT clause  in the where existes subquery

```
        UPDATE irp.irp_plates p 
        SET p.irp_pla_platenbr  = (

            select  vd.plate_reg
            from irp.irp_vehicles  v
            inner join irp.irp_fleetvehicleregistration fvr on fvr.irp_fvr_vehicleid = v.irp_veh_id
            inner join irp.irp_plates p on p.irp_pla_vehicleid = fvr.irp_fvr_vehicleid and p.irp_pla_status = 'A'
            inner join VINDECODE.veh_2019 vd on vd.title_number = v.irp_veh_titlenbr
            where v.irp_veh_regdate >= '01-NOV-19'
            and p.irp_pla_platenbr <> vd.plate_reg
            and vd.plate_reg like 'A%'
        )  
        WHERE EXISTS (
            select  vd.plate_reg
            from irp.irp_vehicles  v
            inner join irp.irp_fleetvehicleregistration fvr on fvr.irp_fvr_vehicleid = v.irp_veh_id
            inner join irp.irp_plates p on p.irp_pla_vehicleid = fvr.irp_fvr_vehicleid and p.irp_pla_status = 'A'
            inner join VINDECODE.veh_2019 vd on vd.title_number = v.irp_veh_titlenbr
            where v.irp_veh_regdate >= '01-NOV-19'
            and p.irp_pla_platenbr <> vd.plate_reg
            and vd.plate_reg like 'A%'

        )
```